# Dropbox stopped working following a new router

Tags: router, dropbox

I've recently installed a new TALKTALK Dlink DSL-3782 router, and following this, Dropbox won't sync on my windows 10 PC.

I get the following error on the icon in my toolbar, "can't establish a secure internet connection".

I've tried various things:

a) dropbox > settings > preferences > proxies > No proxie, but this doesn't work

b) Looked in my router firewall settings to make an exclusion, but I cannot see anyware to do this.

Comment: Did you recently switch ISPs?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/cant-establish-secure-connection

Comment: I cannot even view the Dropbox link I get, 'the site can't provide a secure connection' error.

Comment: I didn't change th isp.

Comment: Is your router doing any sort of deep packet inspection using SSL decryption? The Dropbox desktop app uses certificate pinning and is incompatible with man-in-the-middle SSL inspection services. However, the web-access method should still work.

Comment: I can not connect to dropbox.com via Chrome and IE, but can using a TOR browser.

Answer (score 0):

This error might have the following causes:

- Date is incorrect on either your computer or the router,
  if date is too far from the expiration date of the Dropbox SSL certificate
- Proxy or firewall blocking the Dropbox service on computer or router,
  namely internet ports 80 and 443.

The last point you may verify by having your ports scanned from the outside
by a tool such as [ShieldsUP!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2)
(but there are many others).

There are some other possible conflicts if you have also installed
new products, mostly security ones, which might conflict with Dropbox.

Comment: a) I've checked the time and date on the router and the computer, which were both correct. b) I ran a shieldsup which gave "THE EQUIPMENT AT THE TARGET IP ADDRESS
DID NOT RESPOND TO OUR UPnP PROBES!" so not sure what this means. c) I've managed to connect to dropbox using the TOR browser, but the same url doesn't work in Chrome or IE.

Comment: First time for me. Try maybe the [Nmap Online Port Scanner](https://hackertarget.com/nmap-online-port-scanner/).

Comment: Have you checked the router's settings for what it blocks? You might try to turn off its firewall, but turn it on back after a few minutes, as it's pretty dangerous because the Internet is constantly scanned by malware.

Comment: Turning firewall off still didn't let me use dropbox. I'm confused as to why if I put https://www.dropbox.com/ i get "This site can’t provide a secure connection" and "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" with "Try running Windows Network Diagnostics."; but i can access https://www.dropbox.com/ using the TOR browser.

Comment: Nmap scan report
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp   filtered ftp
22/tcp   filtered ssh
23/tcp   filtered telnet
80/tcp   filtered http
110/tcp  filtered pop3
143/tcp  filtered imap
443/tcp  filtered https
3389/tcp filtered ms-wbt-server

Comment: Nmap reference manual: "Filtered means that a firewall, filter, or other network obstacle **is blocking the port** so that Nmap cannot tell whether it is open or closed". Your dropbox ports are blocked. The most likely cause is your router, since it is the one that nmap contacts. Dropbox is supposed to do that for you, so check that Universal Plug and Play (UPnP) is enabled on the router. If it is enabled, you may need to port-forward ports 80 and 443 to your computer for the router to agree to open them, although in general this isn't a good idea to expose them like that.

Comment: Universal Plug and Play (UPnP) is enabled on the router.

Comment: I haven't port forwarded 80 and 443, but there's something on my router to open ports which I did, but still no joy. its called APPLICATION and here is the description of what  it does: "The Application is used to open single or multiple ports in your firewall
when the router senses data sent to the Internet on a outgoing "Trigger" port or port range.
Applications rules apply to all computers on your internal network. "

Comment: In port forwarding you specify the IP of the computer to which this port is diverted. I'm not sure opening is the same.